# How to select the first match of a group of conditions in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table like this:

```
MyTable
-------------------------------
| ID         | from   | to    |
-------------------------------
| 1          | U_002  | C_005 |
| 2          | U_015  | C_004 |
| 3          | C_005  | U_011 |
| 4          | U_008  | C_001 |
| 5          | U_007  | C_005 |
| 6          | U_001  | C_005 |
| 7          | C_004  | U_015 |
| 8          | U_002  | C_002 |
| 9          | U_001  | C_009 |
| 10         | U_010  | C_005 |
| 11         | C_005  | U_001 |
| 12         | U_004  | C_003 |
| 13         | U_005  | C_005 |
| 14         | U_010  | C_001 |
| 15         | C_005  | U_001 |
-------------------------------
```

`ID`, is the Unique Incremental Key of the table.

The goal is:

- By giving a value (for example: `C_005`, `U_001`, `C_010`, etc..) Obtain the first match of this two conditions: `((from == value) || (to == value))` starting from higher `ID`.

This means, that data can be "duplicate", but I only wants the first result of the group.

For example, `C_004` and `U_015`, have TWO entries (`C_004 -> U_015` and `U_015 -> C_004`). This should return only ONE.
Since we want to start from higher `Id`, that mean that it would return only `7 | C_004 | U_015`.

---

Let's put an example:

- Value = `C_005`

The expected output is:

```
15 | C_005 | U_001
13 | U_005 | C_005
10 | U_010 | C_005
 5 | U_007 | C_005
 3 | C_005 | U_011
 1 | U_002 | C_005
```

---

The idea, is to get the ""last"" (because we are starting from higher `Id`) coincidence of TWO values.

As I have said, two values can have multiple coincidences, but I only want to get the "last" one (Higher `Id`).

Comment: ROW_NUMBER() in CTE.

Comment: You write "_Obtain the first match_", but then your expected result has 6 rows. Do you want one row or all?

Comment: Obtain first match for each group of two conditions.

Comment: First match based on what ? Because in your dataset, first match would be ID =1 and output would be only 1 row. But you are expecting 6 rows where value =  'C_005'. so a simple `from = 'C_005' OR to =' C_005' ` should work. why you need group by ?

Comment: The idea is to create “groups” where `from` or `to` equals to value. Then, return the first match of every one of these groups (this is why there are 6 results). And we use ID, to be able to start from higher. PS: i’m not sure is it’s groups the solutions, it’s my guess.

Answer (score 0):

use max()

```
select max(id) id,`from`,`to`
from table_name
group by `from`,`to`
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data is messed up because you have duplicates and potentially cycles too.  Arrggh.  You should fix the data.

But you can still do what you want with a recursive CTE:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select id, f, t, 1 as lev, cast(t as char(1000)) as visited
      from t
      where f in ('C_005') /*, 'U_001', 'C_010') */
      union all
      select t.id, t.f, t.t, lev + 1, concat_ws(',', cte.visited, t.f)
      from cte join
           t
           on cte.f = t.t
      where cte.visited not like concat('%', t.f, '%') 
     )
select distinct id, f, t
from cte
order by id desc;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cc9165a4515151e90f663fc4db7203e9) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks! I have to look it a little bit more to understand it (pretty new into mysql). Imagine this as a “messages” list (i don’t have added the other columns). It has “duplicates”, because it can have more than one message between two “values”.

Comment: Been looking into it, and with this, it's not "filtered" only the first match no? It's giving me also 11 and 6.

Comment: @SpykeRel04D . . . Of course.  Your specify that you want to filter on `'C_005'` and those are also in the set.  If you just want to filter on `id = 3`, then change the first `where` clause for that.

Comment: It's not about `id = 3`." `Obtain the first match of this two conditions: ((from == value) || (to == value)) starting from higher ID`". So the idea is to get only the first "result" of each "group", without repeat data.